# Lost my windows account

Tags: windows-7

I went to Users/myProfile then I right clicked ,went to properties and checked hidden folders then ordered to all sub folders and I waited 3 mins and from then all the subfolders of my profile cannot be found anywhere,so I then went backtrack to uncheck the hidden box and I found out it is unchecked as it was in the beginning.Any help please!

Windows7 64bit Ultimate

Comment: What makes you think it has been "erased"? What error message do you get when you try to log in using that account? What recovery efforts have you tried? When asking a question, [please be specific](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry for my quickness of describing, I went to Users again and I can't see my profile or anything sub to it, I went then to properties tab after right clicking and again the hidden box was unchecked as in the beginning

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include more details, rather than responding with another comment. Comments should be reserved to *requesting* more information or *suggesting* improvements.

Comment: **What was open exactly?**

Comment: I mean the check box (hidden files ) was unchecked as in the beggining

Comment: #1: profiles aren't ever hidden by default (as in, you have to hide them manually), so you shouldn't have to show hidden files to see whether your profile directory is in \Users\. 

#2, you're describing one part of your issue. Can you give us details on what you see when you try to log on? What you were doing before the whole thing blew up? What you're hoping to see once it's fixed?

Comment: I've done now a system restore and fixed my isssue, I didn't had any problem logging in my profile , I had problems when I tried to reach any subfolder under Users/myAccount/... (for example I couldn't find my downloads) .Now after the system restore some files & some archives where hidden and I had to unhidden them, everything is a bit strange hopefully a recovered well.